# Google map doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my rails application I'm trying to use google maps javascript api to render map in partial view. Basically I've done the same thing as described on google documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), however my api request doesn't return anything and map doesn't show up.

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testt</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyHkeUeKHSHKNPUHkAeYHDFE0ZBwGvBF&callback=initMap&libraries=places" async defer></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Parial view:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter place">
<div id="type-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
  <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
  <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
  <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
  <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

js file:

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
  zoom: 13
});
var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));

var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  infowindow.close();
  marker.setVisible(false);
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }

  // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
  }
  marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
  }));
  marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
  marker.setVisible(true);

  var address = '';
  if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
  }

  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
function setupClickListener(id, types) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    autocomplete.setTypes(types);
  });
}

setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try giving a height and width to div

```
<div id="map"  style="width:300px; height:300px;">
```